# ROR: Creating a method with a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have an admins dashboard which displays posts created in the last 24 hours, 7 days, 28 days etc.

```
def index
  @1DayPosts = Post.where(created_at: 1.days.ago..DateTime.now).count 
  @7DaysPosts = Post.where(created_at: 7.days.ago..DateTime.now).count 
  @28DaysPosts = Post.where(created_at: 28.days.ago..DateTime.now).count 
end
```

How could I make this into one line? Something like the below:

```
def index
  @calculatePosts(a) = Post.where(created_at: a.days.ago..DateTime.now).count 
end
```

Then in the view I could do:

```
=@calculatePosts(1)
```

Or would I need to create a new method?

```
def calculatePosts(a)
    @calculatePost = Post.where(created_at: a.days.ago..DateTime.now).count
end
```

How would I then call this in the index view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a scope on the `Post` model.

```
class Post ...

  scope :last_x_days, -> (x) { where(created_at: x.days.ago..Time.zone.now) }
end
```

Then you can call that anywhere really, in your view or controller like this.

```
@last_10_days = Post.last_x_days(10).count
```

---

*EDIT:*

You could do this also, but scopes are meant to be chain-able, so this is discouraged, though not wrong.

```
scope :last_x_days_count, -> (x) { where(created_at: x.days.ago..Time.zone.now).count }
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! Is it better practice to call `@last_10_days = Post.last_x_days(10).count` in the controller and then in the view just call `@last_10_days` ? Or is better to just call `@last_10_days = Post.last_x_days(10).count` in the view? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Does not really matter, you can just call `Post.last_x_days(10).count` in the view directly, don't really need `@last_10_days` unless you're using it in multiple places in the view.